# Get current sharepoint user id inside a web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to access the currently logged in user when an event fires in a web part. I would typically think to do this with:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser
```

and specifically, to get the ID (what I need):

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID
```

This works as expected in say an event receiver. However, in my example web part, this is returning information about the machine user account. How would I best access the logged in SharePount user instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. When debugging I was logged in as the system account which messed things up. Using a regular user account presented the expected results using the methods above.